# Fragmentation of files

Tags: 12.04

I am seeing declines in performance.   Is there a disk or file defragmentation utility for Ubuntu?   If so, where can I get it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

EXT4 under Ubuntu [has no need for defragmentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary) like Windows does, due to the efficiency of the filesystem. It more or less automatically takes care of all of this for you on the fly.

If you ***really*** want to defrag your system (which can be a really bad idea), a guide is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/620966/208574). To sum it up, run the following command to work on the whole system:

```
sudo e4defrag -c /
```

It will spit back output as it works. If no output returns, the system found nothing to defragment.