# Does Ubuntu need to be defragmented?

Tags: filesystem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is defragmentation unnecessary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary)

Does the filesystem in ubuntu need to be defragment like the Windows??

Answer (score 9):

No Defragmenation is necessary for Ubuntu. Check out an earlier discussion [Why is defragmentation unnecessary?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary)

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that you don't need to defrag a Linux box.

Comment: Not sure why this got a down-vote....

Comment: @jgbelacqua Maybe a windows user?

Comment: Most Linux file systems make it less likely for your files to become severely fragmented, but I can attest to the fact that fragmentation does occur. I could notice that with a very large Virtual Box disk, for which I have created many snapshots over the time.

Comment: Also, to be more specific and helpful, e4defrag seems to work OK for ext4 file systems. The assertion that Linux does not need defragmenting seems to keep popping up even though even intuitively one could realize it's patently false.