# file acess slow after deletion of many files

Tags: filesystem, files

I recently accidentally created millions of files in one folder (rougly 5 million) and due to limitations I couldn't process them correctly (maximum argument count exceeded for wc / ls and such stuff). So I deleted them, which took quite a while, but now they're gone. I deleted the files with a regular `rm`. It weren't any system files.

So the files are definitively deleted, but the system is very slow on file stuff now. `ls`, `cat` and auto-complete by pressing `tab` freezes the terminal for several seconds.

Is this some sort of fragmentation issue? Is it an issue with the files beeing still somehow present?

Comment: it's not fragmentation issue since ext4 file system can't be fragmented. Install BleachBit and try to clear unnessesery files and cache which can cause your problems.

Comment: Yes it can @Alen , [it can be fragmented](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary), but it's not as alarming as NTFS.