# Do I need to do maintenance on Ubuntu like you do on Windows?

Tags: installation

I am wondering if I need to do things like *Defragmentation* and *Clear Cache*, to keep Ubuntu running smoothly like that done on Windows?

Answer (score 5):

Actually Fragmentation is there in NTFS where you install Windows, so you need to do defragmentation. while coming to Ubuntu , we  install it in EXT type partitions & they don't need defragmentation because EXT not stores the data in fragmentation.

So no need of defragmentation for Ubuntu.[To know more about fragmentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary)

while coming to cache , its a single word but connected to all areas of Ubuntu.

If you are running out of space , by clearing cache you can save your space.I do use bleachbit to clear cache that will remove apt-get cache , autoremove , autoclean , browsers cache and other in Ubuntu system. Removing old kernels also gives you more free space.

[To know more about clearing cache](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space)