# Speed Up Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: windows-8, performance

Since i m new one to ubuntu. When using windows 8 OS, there are lot of ways to speed up the system performance. That is why i want to know what are the possible ways for best performance of system.

I have dell-latitude|D610 with 1 GB Ram and 2 Ghz Processor.

Your kind instructions are needed.

Comment: speed is subjective and is effected by hardware, most often video cards and wireless, and by the number of services you are running. you can try k/x/lubuntu or a lighter distro.

Comment: The more logical question would be: Why would an OS come with default settings that slows down a system? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
When using windows 8 OS, there are lot of ways to speed up the system performance
```

Really? How? All I know is that you can

- Refresh: something [you don't need to do in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41929/what-is-the-concept-of-refresh-in-linux-if-there-is-so)
- Defragmentation: You very [rarely need defragmentation,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary) I've been using linux for about 7 years and never defraged a disk.
- Viruses: very few run in Linux, you don't need an antivurus, you could install one if you want but you don't need it, not only viruses slow windows, but some antivirus slow windows even more, trust me, I tried every antivirus, every optimization method before giving up on windows!
- Junk cleaners, such as Ccleaner: On Ubuntu you just do `sudo apt-get autoremove` and  `sudo apt-get autoclean`, those commands will clean stuff you don't need but won't speed up your system, because nothing can slow your system down in the first place.
- If unity, the desktop, itself is slow,  you could switch to Xubuntu,
  if you want something faster, you can get Openbox, there are many
  options.
- If your browser is slow, you could clear cache or switch to another
  browser, it's something not related to Linux, in fact I find web
  browsing much faster on Linux then on Windows 7. Chrome will eat all
  the ram in windows 7 and become really slow, if you install plugins
  and open few tabs

Now, did I miss something? Is there a way to optimize Windows that I forgot to mention?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really any programs to increase performance in Linux. There's Bleachbit, that cleans cookies, cache, and other stuff, but doesn't really speed anything up. Linux is just supposed to be fast as is. So whatever speed Ubuntu is giving you now is probably the speed you're stuck with.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is , even in windows, there is no such thing as optimizing program. all they is use the utility that come packed with windows. They defragment the system, delete the temporary files, cookies, things like that. They only make a fool out of the novices. So do not pay for such softwares under windows. Use CCleaner and occassionally defragment your hard disk. That should do the trick for Windows

And for the linux part, you don't need one. If you want to remove the temporary files and things like that use BleachBit. But that wont speed up your system. A LINUX system only gets slower when you HD gets filled up and that too is not noticeable.

http://www.howtogeek.com/115229/htg-explains-why-linux-doesnt-need-defragmenting/

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/10/defragmenting-linux-ext3-filesystems.html