# How to defrag ext4 file system on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, ext4, backport, defrag

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 Server with ext4 as file system. e2fsprogs is installed, but e4defrag is only packaged since Ubuntu 12.04. How do I defrag the file system or how can I install e4defrag? Maybe there is a backport of e4defrag for Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1090/why-is-defragmentation-unnecessary  - It is usually not needed to defrag an ext4 file system at all, except maybe if you fill up the disk to more than 90%! This is because unlike the popular Windows file systems FAT and NTFS, ext4 stores data not sequentially from the beginning, but starts in the middle of the disk and works its way to the outsides, always leaving some space around each file so that it may grow without getting split up. It also always tries to put files in one big enough place whenever possible.

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 has reached end of life and so did support from AskUbuntu.

Comment: To close voters: yes it is "end of life" but a dupe close is a better close vote don't you agree ;-)